# Correct way of pattern matching Strings in Erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, pattern-matching

Which of these approaches is better for pattern matching strings in erlang?

```
receiveString("someString") -> %doStuff;
receiveString("differentString") -> %doOtherStuff.
```

or

```
receiveString(A) when A == "someString" -> %doStuff;
receiveString(A) when A == "differentString" -> %doOtherStuff.
```

Also, is it possible to have multiple `when` clauses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are equivalent but the first one is definitely more readable to me as it is way more straightforward.

So I would go with the first one!

---

You can have several guard expressions separated by commas:

```
recieveString(A, B) when A == "some", B == "other" -> %doStuff;
```